# what is the usage of : this.method.bind(this)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm studying Reactjs and have a block of code like this:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
        
      this.state = {
         data: []
      }
    
      this.setStateHandler = this.setStateHandler.bind(this);
   };

   setStateHandler() {
      var item = "setState..."
      var myArray = this.state.data;
      myArray.push(item)
      this.setState({data: myArray})
   };

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <button onClick = {this.setStateHandler}>SET STATE</button>
            <h4>State Array: {this.state.data}</h4>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

After click button, the 'SET STATE' String will appear. But i don't understand the usage of `this.setStateHandler.bind(this);` function.
Can anybody can explain it for me?

Comment: [Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) you should understand it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`this.setStateHandler().bind(this)` sets the context for the function `setStateHandler()` to be the class object. This is necessary so that you could call `this.setState({...})` inside the method, because `setState()` is the method of `React.Component`. If you do not `.bind(this)` you would get an error that `setState()` method is undefined.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that :) still new. What's the best way to handle these questions? Do you just leave them unanswered?

Comment: Mark it as a duplicate (as a few of us have done) and it will get closed and link to that other question, which has lots of great answers already.

Comment: Ok. Was afraid of using flag :) Do I delete my answer?

Comment: You can leave your answer - don't flag it for moderator attention, if you don't have the reputation to mark it as a duplicate just hold on and soon you'll see a "close" button at the bottom of the question which you can use :)

Comment: I don't think that it is a duplicate question...

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate. The linked answer describes the basic functionality of `bind()`, but this question is specifically about `this.someFunction.bind(this);` which does not make sense for the time being (**especially** after reading the linked answer)

Comment: A very good explanation is available at https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/